# Custom cursor animated effects trail

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse-cursor

There is this great addon for WoW that allows you to add FX to the cursor and they create a trail effect that allows you to easily find the cursor, this trail and effect can come in a variety of FXs, mostly it looks like from the game itself.
http://mods.curse.com/addons/wow/cursor

The addon is just for example purposes, but

Can the same thing be done for cursors in Windows 10? If so how? To clarify, I want a custom effect like in the addon, not just a simple trail.

Answer (score 3):

#### Mouse cursor animated effects trail

- Start "Mouse"

  [image]
- Select "Pointer Options"
- Enable "Display pointer trails"
- Press "OK"

  [image]

---

#### I'm looking for a way to customize this effect with different animations

You could consider [CursorFX](http://www.stardock.com/products/cursorfx/) from [Stardock](http://www.stardock.com/):

> Create stunning animated Windows mouse cursors for your PC with
>   CursorFX.
>
> Easily apply skins, shadows, motion trails and sounds to your cursors.
>   CursorFX comes complete with over 12 unique cursors.
>
> **Key Features**
>
> - Customize over 12 anti-aliased 32-bit cursors
> - Create your own cursors
> - Animated cursors and special effects
> - Sound effects for your mouse clicks
>
> **Customize**
>
> Quickly change the size, color or drop shadow of any cursor from the
>   settings menu. Personalize your mouse clicks with cool sounds effects.
>   Add a unique visual style to your cursors by applying different
>   combinations of special effects and motion trails that are included
>   with CursorFX.
>
> Thousands of additional custom cursors are available for download from our community at WinCustomize.com

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [Stardock](http://www.stardock.com/) in any way, I am just an end user of their software.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to customize this effect with different animations and things, the trail itself is copies of the pointer, there's no option for custom effects here.

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer Then please edit your question to make that clear.

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer Answer updated with one possibility.

Comment: thanks, it's a good answer but my first concern would be does CursorFX work with games? Many games override the OS cursor, I want to retain the trail in games, it's the primary reason for this is to be able to see the mouse via this eye-catching custom animation trail in any program.

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer I've no idea - I don't play games. However, if the game is providing its own cursor then CursorFX probably won't help.

Comment: i wonder if it would be possible to write a custom app to do it then, is cursorfx based on C++?

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer I've no idea.

Answer (score -1):

I came here looking for exact same thing ! As far as i know 
what CursorTrail addon does is it slaps a 3D FX model on top of a cursor and makes it follow same coordinates, but it's not as easily done in Windows because there is no 3D engine to run it in.